# Match ID from col1 in col2, take value of that row's col3 if it is less than col3's value in the row that is being matched in col1

Tags: r

I have a DF like this:

```
ID_A <- c(NA,NA,132,NA,NA,NA,248,NA)
ID_B <- c(132,248,248,381,248,290,290,132)
entry <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6)
df <- data.frame(ID_A,ID_B,entry)
```

And I'm looking to add a result column that would look like this:

```
df$result <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,4,NA)
```

For each row if ID_A is not `NA`, I want to find the corresponding value in the entry col where: 1) ID_A matches ID_B and 2) ID_A's entry column is the greatest value that is not greater than the entry value for the row of the ID_A that we're matching in ID_B.

My attempt, which feels like it might be close, but currently doesn't find the correct values:

```
df$result <- ifelse(is.na(df$ID_A),NA,df$entry[match(df$ID_A,df$ID_B) & !duplicated(df$ID_B,fromLast = TRUE)])
```

Comment: The wording is very confusing but I think I get what you're trying to say. How are you dealing with repeated values? The 132 value in ID_A  could map to 1 or 6 if you don't specify you want the first possible value

Comment: This has the makings of a `merge` (or `dplyr::*_join`) if not for the dupes @FelipeFlores highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is sorted by `entry` (as in the example)...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[!is.na(ID_A), v := 
  df[.SD, on=.(ID_B = ID_A, entry < entry), mult="last", x.entry]
]

   ID_A ID_B entry result  v
1:   NA  132     1     NA NA
2:   NA  248     2     NA NA
3:  132  248     2      1  1
4:   NA  381     3     NA NA
5:   NA  248     4     NA NA
6:   NA  290     5     NA NA
7:  248  290     5      4  4
8:   NA  132     6     NA NA
```

*How it works*

`x[i, ..., j]` executes `j` on a subset of `x` determined by `i`.

- A simple subset can be defined by a filtering condition in `i`, like `!is.na(ID_A)`.
- Alternately, a subset can be defined by a join with a table in `i`. Here, the join is of `x = df` with `i = .SD = df[!is.na(ID_A)]`, the "Subset of Data" defined in the first bullet; and `on=` and `mult=` are conditions on the join.

The `on=` conditions are written like `.(xcol1 = icol1, xcol2 < icol2)` where `xcol`s belong to `x` and `icol`s to `i`. In `j` after a join, cols from each table can be accessed with prefixes like `x.entry` here to disambiguate which table to pull from.

`mult=` determines what happens when there are multiple matches from the `on=` conditions. Here, we have ID 248 with entries at both 2 and 4. Since the data is sorted by `entry` (within a given `ID_B`), `mult="last"` will select the greater value.

Finally, `j` can be used to modify columns, like `x[i, ..., newcol := values]`, which only operates on the subset of `x` defined by `i`.

Comment: `Error in `:=`(v, df[.SD, on = .(ID_B = ID_A, entry < entry), mult = "last",  : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").`

Comment: @imi Thanks. I forgot a line; hope it works after my edit